# Are "I am not able to do this" questions related to Photoshop, Gimp, or Illustrator okay on GD.SE?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, close-reasons, quality-evaluation, asking-questions

Yes, I searched this site, and found many Photoshop-related questions, BUT none like this. So, please read on.

I would like to know if asking *"I am not able to do this..."* questions related to Photoshop, Gimp, or Illustrator (or any other popular graphic design tool) okay on GD.SE?

For example, consider that I am [following this tutorial](http://www.psdgraphics.com/tutorials/google-logo-photoshop-tutorial/) about creating a Google logo from scratch. My end-result isn't even close (and I don't know why), can I show the steps I followed, and ask for help as to what I am doing wrong?

This is basically a how-to question, either way you see it. And that's troubling me a bit (considering the rules).

Comment: I [just read this](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3/should-this-se-site-include-technical-questions-ie-photoshop-etc) `A site focused on graphic design, including icon/logo design, colors and typography. Questions regarding the tools of the trade (Photoshop, Illustrator, etc.) are also allowed, as long as they're relevant.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part, "why doesn't my design achieve {effect}" is *exactly* the type of question we want to encourage.

In general, if you want to ask a question about the specific steps required to do something - you might get blown off as requesting a tutorial.  However, if you list what you have tried, and demonstrate the effect you created and how it differs from the desired effect, people will likely be eager to help.

A word of advice though -- I do not recommend posting a bunch of screencaps of your layer effects and asking which one is different from the tutorial.  Instead you may want to post your resulting image and state where it fails.  Most of the designers here will likely be able to pinpoint the issue with a glance.

Comment: @Lauren Good eyes, thanks.  :)

Comment: You're welcome. My other hat has "Editor" on it. :)